# I want to add EDIT and DELETE functionality on a ListTile

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to add **delete** and **edit** functionality in my lists using **PopMenuItem**. As shown in the picture, when I click on menu icon on any list, two options appears, when I click on delete button, it should delete that complete list, and when I click on edit, it should let me edit those Text Fields in ListTile, so far I have attempted this code to delete list, but it isn't working. And I have no idea, how can I achieve that **edit functionality** in this, Someone please help me out.
Here is the picture:[image]

Here is the code to delete list:

```
PopupMenuItem(
      child: FlatButton(
             child: Text('Delete'),
                onPressed: () {
                       widget.models.removeAt(index);
                        setState(() => widget.models = widget.models);
                 },
              ),
       ),
```

And here is the complete code:

```
class DialogForm extends StatefulWidget {
  // List<Model> models = <Model>[];
  // Model tempModel = Model();
  // final newModel = Model();

  DialogForm();

  @override
  State<DialogForm> createState() => _ResultState();
  List<Model> models = <Model>[];
  Model tempModel = Model();
  @override
  void debugFillProperties(DiagnosticPropertiesBuilder properties) {
    super.debugFillProperties(properties);
    properties.add(DiagnosticsProperty<Model>('model', tempModel));
  }
}

class _ResultState extends State<DialogForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Successful')),

      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[

            Flexible(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: widget.models.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) => Card(
                      elevation: 6,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: PopupMenuButton<String>(
                        onSelected: (String value) {
                          setState(() {
                          });
                        },
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text(widget.models[index].firstName),
                          subtitle: Text(widget.models[index].lastName),
                          trailing: Icon(Icons.menu),
                        ),
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry<String>>[
                          PopupMenuItem(
                            child: FlatButton(
                              child: Text('Edit'),
                              onPressed: () {

                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                          PopupMenuItem(
                            child: FlatButton(
                              child: Text('Delete'),
                              onPressed: () {
                                widget.models.removeAt(index);
                                setState(() => widget.models = widget.models);
                              },
                            ),
                          ),

                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                )

            ),


            Align(
              child: RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Click Me!'),
                  onPressed: (){
                showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (BuildContext context){
                      return AlertDialog(
                        content: Stack(
                          overflow: Overflow.visible,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Positioned(
                              right: -40,
                              top: -40,
                              child: InkResponse(
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                },
                                child: CircleAvatar(
                                  child: Icon(Icons.close),
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Form(
                                key: _formKey,
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: MyTextFormField(
                                        hintText: 'First Name',
                                        validator: (String value) {
                                          if (value.isEmpty) {
                                            return 'Enter your first name';
                                          }
                                          return null;
                                        },
                                        onSaved: (String value) {
                                          widget.tempModel.firstName = value;
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: MyTextFormField(
                                        hintText: 'Last Name',
                                        validator: (String value) {
                                          if (value.isEmpty) {
                                            return 'Enter your last name';
                                          }
                                          return null;
                                        },
                                        onSaved: (String value) {
                                          print(value);
                                          widget.tempModel.lastName = value;
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: MyTextFormField(
                                        hintText: 'Enter email',
                                        isEmail: true,
                                        // validator: (String value) {
                                        //   if (!validator.isEmail(value)) {
                                        //     return 'Please enter a valid email';
                                        //   }
                                        //   return null;
                                        // },
                                        onSaved: (String value) {
                                          widget.tempModel.email = value;
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: RaisedButton(
                                        child: Text("Submit"),
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          // var m = widget.tempModel;
                                          // print(m.firstName + "" + m.lastName + "" + m.email);
                                          // return;
                                          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                            _formKey.currentState.save();
                                            //  var m = widget.tempModel;
                                            // print(m.firstName + "" + m.lastName + "" + m.email);
                                            widget.models.add(Model.fromModel(widget.tempModel));

                                            setState(() {
                                              widget.models = widget.models;
                                              // widget.tempModel.add(new widget.models());
                                            }
                                            );
                                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                          }
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                )
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    }

                );
              }

              ),
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            ),
          ],

        ),
      ),
    )
    );
  }
}

class MyTextFormField extends StatelessWidget {
  final String hintText;
  final Function validator;
  final Function onSaved;
  final bool isPassword;
  final bool isEmail;

  MyTextFormField({
    this.hintText,
    this.validator,
    this.onSaved,
    this.isPassword = false,
    this.isEmail = false,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: hintText,
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          border: InputBorder.none,
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
        ),
        obscureText: isPassword ? true : false,
        validator: validator,
        onSaved: onSaved,
        keyboardType: isEmail ? TextInputType.emailAddress : TextInputType.text,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```